# Pyspark: filter dataframe by regex with string formatting?

Tags: regex, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've read several posts on using the "like" operator to filter a spark dataframe by the condition of containing a string/expression, but was wondering if the following is a "best-practice" on using %s in the desired condition as follows:

```
input_path = <s3_location_str>
my_expr = "Arizona.*hot"  # a regex expression
dx = sqlContext.read.parquet(input_path)  # "keyword" is a field in dx

# is the following correct?
substr = "'%%%s%%'" %my_keyword  # escape % via %% to get "%"
dk = dx.filter("keyword like %s" %substr)

# dk should contain rows with keyword values such as "Arizona is hot."
```

**Note**

I'm trying to get all rows in dx that **contain** the expression my_keyword. Otherwise, for exact matches we wouldn't need surrounding percent signs '%'.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From neeraj's hint, it seems like the correct way to do this in pyspark is:

```
expr = "Arizona.*hot"
dk = dx.filter(dx["keyword"].rlike(expr))
```

Note that `dx.filter($"keyword" ...)` did not work since (my version) of pyspark didn't seem to support the `$` nomenclature out of the box.

Comment: I'd recommend using implicit column selection, as opposed to referencing `dx` twice.  e.g., `dk = dk.filter(F.col("keyword").rlike(expr))`.  This is recommended per the [Palantir PySpark Style Guide](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/pyspark-style-guide/index.html#prefer-implicit-column-selection-to-direct-access-except-for-disambiguation), as it makes the code more portable (you don't have to update `dk` in both locations).

For clarity, you'll need `from pyspark.sql import functions as F`.

Answer (score 13):

Try rlike function as mentioned below.

```
df.filter(<column_name> rlike "<regex_pattern>")
```

for example.

```
dk = dx.filter($"keyword" rlike "<pattern>")
```

Comment: Is this Scala? Pyspark doesn't seem to support `col rlike expr` syntax.

Answer (score 8):

I used the following for the timestamp regex

```
expression = r'[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) (2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]'
df1 = df.filter(df['eta'].rlike(expression))
```