# How to find a string in each row in a dataframe in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here is the data frame available:

```
+--------------------+
|                Name|
+--------------------+
|Braund, Mr. Owen ...|
|Cumings, Mrs. Joh...|
|Heikkinen, Miss. ...|
|Futrelle, Mrs. Ja...|
|Allen, Mr. Willia...|
|Moran, Mr. James|
|McCarthy, Mr. Tim...|
|Palsson, Master. ...|
|Johnson, Mrs. Osc...|
+--------------------+
```

I want to find the first occurrence of Title and Surname in each row in DATA FRAME using Pyspark (Pandas lib is not available in my cluster).

```
pattern=re.compile(r'(Dr|Mrs?|Ms|Miss|Master|Rev|Capt|Mlle|Col|Major|Sir|Lady|Mme|Don)\\.'
pattern.match(df['Name'])
```

Comment: Maybe something like [this that uses regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45600691/3433323), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41890264/3433323) or with a `udf`.

Comment: @mkaran Tried this code but not successful def findTitle(df):
 rdd=df.select("Name").flatMap(lambda x: x).map(lambda x:x).collect()
 for f in rdd:
   title=re.search('(Dr|Mrs?|Ms|Miss|Master|Rev|Capt|Mlle|Col|Major|Sir|Lady|Mme|Don)',f).group()

Comment: Can you try `df = df.filter(df["Name"].rlike(r'(Ms|Miss)'))` (and `df.show()`)? I couldn't get it to work with your regex but it definitely works with this simpler expression.

Comment: Btw, if you want the surname your regex should be modified to something that uses lookbehind, e.g. `(?<=Mr\.\s)\w+` will match `Owen` from the first line etc.

Comment: @mkaran df = df.filter(df["Name"].rlike(r'(Ms|Miss)')) .I have pattern for more than 15 surname.Its not working for me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regexp_extract` as @Prem suggested but with a different regex pattern, depending on what you need:

```
# do not keep the first two groups, just what follows, the surname:
pattern = r'(?:(?:Dr|Mrs?|Ms|Miss|Master|Rev|Capt|Mlle|Col|Major|Sir|Lady|Mme|Don)\.?\s?)(\w+)'

# or keep both title and surname
pattern_with_title = r'((Dr|Mrs?|Ms|Miss|Master|Rev|Capt|Mlle|Col|Major|Sir|Lady|Mme|Don)\.?\s?)(\w+)'

#sample data
df = spark.createDataFrame([["Braund, Mr. Owen other stuff"], 
                       ["Cumings, Mrs. Joh some details"], 
                       ["Heikkinen, Miss. Hellen blah"], 
                       ["Futrelle, Mrs. Ja .... .... "]], ["Name"])

df.show()

+-----------------+
|             Name|
+-----------------+
| Braund, Mr. Owen|
|Cumings, Mrs. Joh|
| Heikkinen, Miss.|
|Futrelle, Mrs. Ja|
+-----------------+

# create a column with what matches the pattern
df = df.withColumn("Surname", regexp_extract("Name", pattern, 1))

df.show()
# keeps only the Surname
+-----------------+---------+
|             Name|  Surname|
+-----------------+---------+
| Braund, Mr. Owen| Owen    |
|Cumings, Mrs. Joh| Joh     |
| Heikkinen, Miss.| Hellen  |
|Futrelle, Mrs. Ja| Ja      |
+-----------------+---------+

 # in case you want both title and Surname:
 df = df.withColumn("Surname with title", regexp_extract("Name", pattern_with_title, 1))

+-----------------+---------+--------------------+
|             Name|  Surname|  Surname with title|
+-----------------+---------+--------------------+
|Braund, Mr. Owen | Owen    | Mr. Ownen          |
|Cumings, Mrs. Joh| Joh     | Mrs. Joh           |
|Heikkinen, Miss..| Hellen  | Miss. Hellen       |
|Futrelle, Mrs. Ja| Ja      | Mrs. Ja            |
+-----------------+---------+--------------------+
```

If you need the full Name, title Surname, then slightly change the pattern to include those too, e.g.:

```
main_pattern = r'Dr|Mrs?|Ms|Miss|Master|Rev|Capt|Mlle|Col|Major|Sir|Lady|Mme|Don'

pattern_full = r'(\w+,?\s('+ main_pattern+')\.?\s?\w+)'
pattern_name = r'(?:(?:'+ main_pattern+')\.?\s?)(\w+)'
pattern_title = r'(?:('+ main_pattern+')\.?\s?)'
pattern_surname = r'(\w+)(?:\,\s?(?:'+ main_pattern+')\.?\s?)'

df = df.withColumn("Full Name", regexp_extract("Name", pattern_full, 1))
df = df.withColumn("First Name", regexp_extract("Name", pattern_name, 1))
df = df.withColumn("Surname", regexp_extract("Name", pattern_surname, 1))
df = df.withColumn("Title", regexp_extract("Name", pattern_title, 1))

df.show(10, False)

+------------------------------+-----------------------+----------+------------+-----+
|Name                          |Full Name              |Surname   |First Name  |Title|
+------------------------------+-----------------------+----------+------------+-----+
|Braund, Mr. Owen other stuff  |Braund, Mr. Owen       |Braund    |Owen        |Mr   |
|Cumings, Mrs. Joh some details|Cumings, Mrs. Joh      |Cumings   |Joh         |Mrs  |
|Heikkinen, Miss. Hellen blah  |Heikkinen, Miss. Hellen|Heikkinen |Hellen      |Miss |
|Futrelle, Mrs. Ja .... ....   |Futrelle, Mrs. Ja      |Futrelle  |Ja          |Mrs  |
+------------------------------+-----------------------+----------+------------+-----+
```

It is all about which part to ignore and which part to select in the regex. Hope this helps, good luck!

Note: not the optimal regex and it has room to improve.

Comment: but I required +-----------------+---------+--------------------+
|             Name|  Surname|   title|
+-----------------+---------+--------------------+
|Braund, Mr. Owen | Owen    | Mr.          |
|Cumings, Mrs. Joh| Joh     | Mrs.           |
|Heikkinen, Miss..| Hellen  | Miss.       |
|Futrelle, Mrs. Ja| Ja      | Mrs           |
+-----------------+---------

Comment: @shalu, that was not clear in your question, could you update it please? I have updated the answer to include many different combinations, let me know if it covers your question. Thanks

Comment: I updated it.I want first occurrence of title and surname in each row.The pattern of surname and title is provide explicitly.

Comment: @shalu thank you! I see that I had name-surname the other way. I've updated my answer. Does it cover your needs?

Comment: thanks, that what I wanted the Title column.Yes It covers my requirement.

Comment: @shalu glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

If `Name` column has 'Surname' as the first word then you can try this else regex would need a little bit of tweaking.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract, col

#sample data
df= sc.parallelize([["Braund, Mr. Owen"], 
                    ["Cumings, Mrs. Joh"], 
                    ["Heikkinen, Miss."], 
                    ["Futrelle, Mrs. Ja"]]).toDF(["Name"])

df = df.withColumn('Surname', regexp_extract(col('Name'), '(\S+),.*', 1))
df.show()
```

Sample data:

```
+-----------------+
|             Name|
+-----------------+
| Braund, Mr. Owen|
|Cumings, Mrs. Joh|
| Heikkinen, Miss.|
|Futrelle, Mrs. Ja|
+-----------------+
```

Output is:

```
+-----------------+---------+
|             Name|  Surname|
+-----------------+---------+
| Braund, Mr. Owen|   Braund|
|Cumings, Mrs. Joh|  Cumings|
| Heikkinen, Miss.|Heikkinen|
|Futrelle, Mrs. Ja| Futrelle|
+-----------------+---------+
```

Comment: I want the title name like Mr. Miss. and sure I will close as soon as I find answer.